# during runtime with sql permanently add some new tables to database not replace table, update database and insert the new tables into

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to add new tables to an existing database in Visual Studio# during runtime and leave them in the database permanently, so that I can edit the data later. In the test, I managed to create the new table with the new name (I write variable in a text field). BUT unfortunately when I quit/close the program. Then, every time in the Sql-Server Explorer the last table. For example, I'll create table named "Test1". Good. the table is then displayed to me in Sql-Express-Server-Explorer. Next time, I'll create a table called "NEWTtable". Then in the explorer I see this table "NEWTtable" but the one before "Test1" has disappeared.
I always have only   1 table in my database? But i would like to add new tables into the database and have more tables in it... and not replace the older table.
I hope my you can understand my bad english. I would like to explain it in german, but i dont know if here someone understand german?

My code:

```
       string neuerTabellenname;
       neuerTabellenname = txtEingabe.Text;

       //Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server.
       string connetionString;
       SqlConnection cnn;
       connetionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Test1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
       cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
       cnn.Open();
      
       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [" + neuerTabellenname + "] (Test1 char(50),Test2 char(50));", cnn))
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();

       MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
       cnn.Close();
```

i hope someone has an idea to update many new tables during prgramm runtime into the database
thanks

Comment: You might want to look into [entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) and [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). This provides a way to both interact with the database, and managing changes to the schema. That is typically easier and more reliable than writing SQL queries yourself.

Comment: You didn't outsmart yourself because you copy your "Test1.mdf" into the targetfolder on every build? So you start every run with a fresh new empty database?

Comment: Also, SO is an english only site, There are [some sites for other languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322313/what-are-the-localized-versions-and-where-can-i-find-them), but as far as I know, no german version.

Comment: `AttachDbfilename` is causing the issue: it creates a copy of the database and deletes it after it's closed. Instead just attach your database normally using `CREATE DATABASE... FOR ATTACH` in SSMS, then connect directly using the connection string to that database name.